# Finding pdf of $Y=\min\{X_1,X_2,...,X_n\}$

Tags: probability, probability-theory, probability-distributions, random-variables, order-statistics

Let $X_1,X_2,...,X_n$ random indepedent variables  that  follow the same distribution with a pdf $f$ and possibility function $F$.Find the pdf of $Y=\min\{X_1,X_2,...,X_n\}$.

My solution: $F_Y(a)=P(Y<a)=P(\min\{X_1,X_2,...,X_n\}<a)$ ,if we let $X_k$ with $k \in \{1,2,...,n\}$ be the min then $F_Y(a)=P(X_k<a)=F_{X_k}(a)$ . So it follows that $f_X(y)=f_{X_k}(x)=f_{X_i}(x)$ for every $i \in \{1,2,...,n\}$ since $X_i$ follow the same pdf.

I dont really thing that answers the question but it is an obvious note.
Could someone help ?
Thank you in advance !

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let $X_{(1)}:=\min(X_k,k\leq n)$
$$\begin{aligned}P(X_{(1)}\leq x)&=P\bigg(\bigcup_{k\leq n}\{X_k\leq x\}\bigg)=\\
&=1-P\bigg(\bigcap_{k\leq n}\{X_k> x\}\bigg)=\\
&=1-(P(X_1>x))^n=\\
&=1-(1-P(X_1\leq x))^n
\end{aligned}$$
So
$$\frac{d}{dx}P(X_{(1)}\leq x)=n(1-P(X_1\leq x))^{n-1}f_{X_1}(x)$$

Comment: Great answer!  Can you comment on the case when $X_i$ have a discrete distribution like Poisson?

Comment: @orangeskid thanks! In the case of discrete distributions we don't have a pdf in the usual sense, so I would stop at the minimum distribution step

Comment: Thank you a lot !

Comment: Of course, the probability *mass* function will be $\mathsf P(X_{(1)} =x)= \mathsf P(X_{(1)} \leq x)-\mathsf P(X_{(1)} \leq x-1)$ ... *if* the variables are integer-valued.